# Windows 10 unexplained high memory usage

Tags: windows-10, memory

My Windows 10 PC with 8GB RAM is experiencing high memory usage (>80%), but when I looked into the Task Manager I can't see any processes with high memory usage.

When I just started my PC, the memory usage is already at 70%.

Task Manager processes:

[image: Task Manager Processes]

Memory performance:

[image: Memory performance]

User memory usage:

[image: User memory usage]

RamMap:

[image: RAMMap]

Comment: Firefox [any browser] would be prime suspect. 10 tabs open. Click the reveal arrow to the left > & add each revealed figure to the total 1189 already shown to get its current usage.

Comment: Compared to my 8GB laptop at the moment, the main difference on RAMMap is active mapped files. You can use the two file tabs in RAMMap to investigate. Your Kernel Stack is also higher. I don't know what would cause that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Task Manager and memory usage](https://superuser.com/questions/385110/task-manager-and-memory-usage)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Having the same issue, also with many mapped files...